# React / React Native: How do I use callback ref in functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-ref

In this library: https://github.com/wix/react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview

From this two lines of code quoted from the readme (**Auto-Scrolling for TextInput components** section), the parent component can get the ref array of the children using the callback ref technique:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView 
    style={styles.container} 
    getTextInputRefs={() => { return [this._textInputRef];}}
>
    <TextInput 
        style={styles.textInput} 
        placeholder={'My Input'} 
        ref={(r) => { this._textInputRef = r; }}
    />

</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

> getTextInputRefs is a callback in which you can return an array of references to the child TextInput components that laid inside the scrollView.

However, to my understanding in functional component there is no such thing like `this._textInputRef`. How do I do the same in which the parent scrollview and the child inputs are functional components?

Not necessary to use this as an example, but will be great to use it.

Any proof of concept is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using refs in a functional component.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const textRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView getTextInpurRefs={() => [textRef]}>
      <TextInput ref={textRef} />
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

For example:

```
export default () => {
    const textInputRef = React.useRef(null);
    return (
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView 
            style={styles.container} 
            getTextInputRefs={() => { return [textInputRef];}}
        >
            <TextInput 
                style={styles.textInput} 
                placeholder={'My Input'} 
                ref={textInputRef}
            />
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    );
}
```